# Android box for debugging android TV application

Tags: android-tv

Which Android box is suitable for testing and debugging android TV application?
I search some android boxes that links are given below :-

https://www.asus.com/us/Home-Entertainment/Nexus_Player/

http://www.mi.com/en/mibox/

Can these devices that is available on above link is compatible for debugging and testing Android TV application? If some know about other android tv box that is suitable for android testing and debugging Android TV application, please provide me link.

Comment: Any box will do

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever brand you want. You should check minimum Android version of application. Device's Android version must be equal or higher

You can check it from [here](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)